# What is the purpose of the tag 'études'?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

The tag [études](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%c3%a9tudes) does not have a tag wiki excerpt. The tag sounds ambiguous to me:

1. Does it refer to **studying or learning** the French language?
2. Does it refer to **scientific / linguistic studies** about (certain aspects of) the French language?

When I look at the questions that have this tag, they seem to be about learning French. If this how the tag was meant to be used, what would be an appropriate tag wiki excerpt? Possibly the following?

> L'étude ou l'apprentissage de la langue française.

Answer (score 5):

It has exclusively been used to refer to studying or learning the language.
We could actually consider renaming it to [apprentissage](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apprentissage). It would help lift the ambiguity. Before doing so, it may be wise to post this on meta as a separate request, as someone could come up with an even better choice.

A possible tag excerpt:

> Méthodes et procédés d'apprentissage de la langue française.

Notice that it has mostly been used in combination with [ressources](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ressources). Sometimes it's about learning techniques. And [one question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/14195/) is about expectations.

Comment: Thanks. I have created a [separate question](http://meta.french.stackexchange.com/q/637/11052) about renaming the tag. I hope it is sufficiently clear that the idea and the proposed wording come from you.