# Proposal: rename tag 'études' to 'apprentissage'?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

In my [previous question](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/q/635/11052), I mentioned that I find the tag [études](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%c3%a9tudes) ambiguous.

As Stéphane Gimenez [pointed out](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/a/636/11052), the tag [études](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%c3%a9tudes) has mainly been used for questions about studying or learning the language. For this reason, I would propose to rename the tag [études](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%c3%a9tudes) to [apprentissage](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apprentissage), with the following tag wiki excerpt, as suggested by Stéphane Gimenez:

> Méthodes et procédés d'apprentissage de la langue française.

**Update**: The related question [What is the purpose of the tag 'études'?](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/q/635/11052) asked for clarification about the purpose of the tag [études](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%c3%a9tudes), whereas this question relies on the outcome of the other question to make a change proposal. It expects a different kind of action: either rename the tag, or reject the proposal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the purpose of the tag 'études'?](http://meta.french.stackexchange.com/questions/635/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-tag-%c3%a9tudes)

Comment: In my opinion both questions should be merged, by editing the previous question. It's really the same question, with a suggestion added.

Comment: @PERCE-NEIGE This question has been created purposely following a moderator request. Please read the other question answer.

Comment: @PERCE-NEIGE As I have already clarified in my update to the question itself, the other question was a *request for clarification* whereas this question is a *request for action*.

Comment: @Jiliagre Je ne parle pas aux gens qui ne savent pas respecter leur interlocuteur, c'est un principe de base. J'ai déjà demandé poliment que tu m'ignores. Il y a vraiment des gens qui ne savent pas être raisonnables...

Comment: @Christophe Dans ce cas, je comprends. Désolée si ça ma proposition arrive comme un cheveu sur la soupe, ce n'était qu'une proposition.

Comment: @PERCE-NEIGE Is it possible to get rid of the "duplicate" label?

Comment: Oui, par le vote des gens; Si personne n'est d'accord, je pense ce ne sera pas "duplicate". Tu penses que c'est gênant pour obtenir des réponses? Je ne sais pas, tant qu'il n'est pas fermé pour "doublon", le sujet reste ouvert. J'essayerai de faire quelque chose si vraiment tu penses que ça met un frein aux réponses.

Answer (score 1):

Since no one disagreed nor came up with different suggestions, I went on and renamed the tag to [apprentissage](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apprentissage), which [études](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%c3%a9tudes) has now become a synonym of.